# Where to get Oracle jar files for 11.2.0.3 - xdb, aq, i18n, xmlparser

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle-aq, oracle-xdk

I'm trying to update a legacy Java application to be compatible with Oracle 11g version 11.2.0.3.

The application was running on Oracle 10g version 10.2.0.4 and uses Oracle Advanced Queues. It has Maven dependencies declared for:

- aq 10.2.0.4.0
- xdb 10.2.0.4.0
- xmlparser 10.2.0.4.0
- i18n 10.2.0.4.0

I'm struggling to find the same files for 11g, specifically for 11.2.0.3. I've looked around in various places such as my Oracle home directory, JDeveloper installation and online, and found a bewildering variety of jar files of various names and versions that are candidates but not quite what I need.

Can anyone let me know where to find the right jar files?

It seems that there are now some `aq` classes in the JDBC driver, but the package name has changed from `oracle.aq` to `oracle.jdbc.aq`. Whilst I'm happy to do some refactoring I'd like some confidence that this is the right thing to do before going ahead. Any advice here would be valuable.

**Edit:**
When trying to run with the mish-mash of versions I've managed to find I get the following error when trying to run the apps unit tests:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.i18n.text.converter.CharacterConverterOGS.getInstance(I)Loracle/i18n/text/converter/CharacterConverter;
at oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.make(CharacterConverterFactoryOGS.java:43)
at oracle.sql.CharacterSetWithConverter.getInstance(CharacterSetWithConverter.java:97)
at oracle.sql.CharacterSetFactoryThin.make(CharacterSetFactoryThin.java:129)
at oracle.sql.CharacterSet.make(CharacterSet.java:514)
at oracle.sql.CHAR.<clinit>(CHAR.java:72)
```

**Edit:**
Managed to solve the problem that was causing the error in my unit tests by downloading `orai18n.jar` and `xdb6.jar` from [Oracle's Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html). However, I'm still short of `aq` and `xmlparser`.

**Edit:**
Found [the Oracle XDK home page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/xmldevkit/index.html) which looks promising for getting `xmlparser`, but there are no downloads available in an obvious place.

Comment: Sorry - thought this was obvious from the title :) - Can anyone let me know where to find the right jar files?

Comment: If you have some candidate jar files, you could look inside their `META-INF/MANIFEST` files, which usually contains a version number entry.

Comment: Thanks. I know what versions I've managed to get already - aq-11.1.0.7.0, i18n-11.2.0.3.0 (correct one for me), xdb-11.1.0 and xmlparser-11.1.0.7.0. This mish-mash of versions is giving me the error above.

Comment: Is it possible to get the XDK files from the Oracle Maven repo these days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Oracle Database 11g Release 2 JDBC Drivers

xdb6 and the drivers are here

Edit: Note that oracle 12c drivers will work with 12c and 11g!

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html

Comment: What about for version 11.2.0.2.0, there are no xdb jars listed for those releases?

Comment: try using later version of driver, it doesnt mean you have to upgrade anything in db itself

Answer (score 1):

The JAR files are included with the Oracle full database client.  I don't think the client is available publicly for download for 11.2.0.3 yet, except perhaps as part of Oracle XE.  If you have the Oracle EE install, the standalone, full client is available from disk 4.

You'll find the correct JAR files in the client in $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib, $ORACLE_HOME/lib, $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib, and $ORACLE_HOME/jlib.  Remember to include orai18n-collation.jar when including orai18n.jar for XQJ support, and ONLY use the same version of ojdbcX.jar as the JARs from the client (i.e, don't use ojdbc5.jar or ojdbc14.jar - use ojdbc6.jar).