# Can anyone provide Maven repository for XMLType xdb.jar and xmlparserv2.jar

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, xmltype

I want to insert Oracle XMLType into database through JDBC. I saw in some websites that we need xdb.jar and xmlparserv2.jar for this.

Can anyone provide the Maven repositories and dependencies for these?

Comment: *plz reply fast.. its urgent* ... find in Google.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529215/where-to-get-oracle-jar-files-for-11-2-0-3-xdb-aq-i18n-xmlparser)

Comment: @Raptor i tried , i could find the jars but not their repositories and dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have found that oracle has copyrights for these jars and u wont find them in any public repository
We have to download them from the oracle website and then add the jars manually to your local repository

Answer (score 3):

Check out xdb6.jar on JDBC Download page. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not find those libs in a public Maven repo. 
You must download them from Oracle XDK: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/index-100632.html
Then you install in your local repo following the directions from Maven manual(https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

Answer (score 1):

Using [Oracle Maven repository](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/application/maven/index.html) you can add to your pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlparserv2</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Oracle JDBC, UCP and other dependent jars are now available on Oracle Maven Repository.  Check out the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420647/how-to-download-the-oracle-jdbc-drivers-and-ucp-from-the-oracle-maven-repository  for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has it's own Maven repository, you do however need to register a user on the Oracle Technology Network website before you can use it. More details can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010

For instructions on configuring Sonatype Nexus repository to use the Oracle maven repository you can follow information on this link:
http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/02/19/using-the-oracle-maven-repository-with-nexus/