# How to download the Oracle JDBC drivers and UCP from the Oracle Maven Repository?

Tags: oracle, maven, jdbc, ucp

Is there a way to download different versions of the Oracle JDBC drivers and Universal Connection Pool (UCP) from the Oracle Maven Repository?

Comment: That isn't a question, clearly; [see this Meta post about making announcements](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268672/266304), and why it isn't appropriate.

Comment: That's good to know but this isn't appropriate for Satck Overflow.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, maybe not useful in this case The concept of self answered questions does exist. The needed skill would be to ask a good questions (not asking for recommentations etc.)  which might be difficult and than place an own answer on it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion !! I changed it to a question and answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Oracle JDBC drivers and Universal Connection Pool (ucp.jar) files are now available in the [Oracle Maven Repository](https://maven.oracle.com).  The JDBC drivers and ucp.jar from 11.2.0.4, 12.1.0.1, 12.1.0.2 and 18.3.0.0 releases are available in the Oracle Maven Repository. Complementary jars such as simplefan.jar and ons.jar can also be downloaded from the same location.

Refer to the blog "[Get Oracle JDBC drivers from the Oracle Maven Repository - NetBeans, Eclipse & Intellij](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/get-oracle-jdbc-drivers-from-the-oracle-maven-repo-netbeans-eclipse-intellij)" for step by step guidelines.

Please feel free to share your comments by commenting in this post.

Thanks,
Oracle JDBC & UCP Team

Comment: We need to register on Oracle Maven Repo, and also pass in the credentials in the maven setting xml. Seriously so much fuss?

Comment: Registration is needed, and "`Directory browsing is not allowed on the Oracle Maven Repository`". HOW should I find out if the artifact I'm looking for is there? E.g. where is "xdb.jar" and what are the correct GAV coordinates? How is a mere mortal going to answer this question? Ridiculous.