# Spring batch NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType

Tags: java, oracle, groovy, spring-batch, autocommit

I have a Spring batch project which connect to an Oracle SQL Database, and allow to export/import some data with xls files.

In my job, I do first a delete in the table, before import the data.
Sometimes, the job failed because there is problems in the xls to import.
For example : If I have duplicate lines, I'm gonna have a SQLException for duplicate when the job will insert the lines in database.

I want to simply no commit anything (especially the delete part).
If the job is successful -> commit
If the job failed -> rollback

So I find that I have to put "setAutocommit" to false.

I have my datasource loaded at the beginning of my job, so I do a :

```
dataSource.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);
```

The instructions works, but when I launch the job, I have this error :

```
ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - 
Encountered an error executing step step_excel_sheet_1551274910254 in job importExcelJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.xlsListener' 
defined in class path resource [com/adeo/config/ImportExcelConfig.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener]: 
Factory method 'xlsListener' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/xdb/XMLType
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) 
~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

The Job config is :

```
@Configuration
public class ImportExcelConfig {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger("ImportExcelConfig");

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Resource(name = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean(name = "importExcelJob")
    public Job importExcel(@Qualifier("xlsPartitionerStep") Step xlsPartitionerStep) throws Exception {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importExcelJob").start(xlsPartitionerStep).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xlsPartitionerStep")
    public Step xlsPartitionerStep(@Qualifier("xlsParserSlaveStep") Step xlsParserSlaveStep, XlsPartitioner xlsPartitioner){
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("xls_partitioner_step_builder")
                .partitioner(xlsParserSlaveStep)
                .partitioner("xls_partitioner_step_builder",XlsPartitioner)
                .gridSize(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xlsParserSlaveStep")
    @StepScope
    public Step xlsParserSlaveStep(@Qualifier("step") Step step,XlsSheetPartitioner xlsPartitioner) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("sheet_partitioner_"+System.currentTimeMillis())
                .partitioner(step)
                .partitioner("sheet_partitioner_"+System.currentTimeMillis(),XlsPartitioner)
                .gridSize(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "step")
    @StepScope
    public Step step(@Qualifier("xlsReader") PoiItemReader xlsReader,
                               @Qualifier("jdbcWriter") ItemWriter jdbcWriter,
                                @Qualifier("xlsListener") StepExecutionListener xlsListener
            ) throws Exception {
        return ((SimpleStepBuilder)stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step_excel_sheet_"+System.currentTimeMillis())
                .<Object, Map>chunk(1000)
                .reader(xlsReader)
                .writer(jdbcWriter)
                .listener(xlsListener)
        ).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xlsListener")
    @StepScope
    @DependsOn
    public StepExecutionListener xlsListener() {
        XlsStepExecutionListener listener = new xlsStepExecutionListener();
        listener.setDataSource(dataSource);
        listener.afterPropertiesSet();
        return listener;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jdbcWriter")
    @StepScope
    @DependsOn
    public ItemWriter<Map> jdbcWriter(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[sheetConfig]}") SheetConfig sheetConfig) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Map> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(preparedStatementSetter());
        String sql = sheetConfig.getSqlInsert().replaceAll("#TABLE#", sheetConfig.getTable());
        LOG.info(sql);
        writer.setSql(sql);
        writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
        writer.afterPropertiesSet();
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter(){
        return new ItemPreparedStatementSetter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor testProcessor() {
        return new TestProcessor();
    }

    @Bean(name = "xlsReader")
    @StepScope
    @DependsOn
    public PoiItemReader xlsReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[sheetConfig]}") SheetConfig sheetConfig,
                                       @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[xls]}") File xlsFile) throws IOException {
        PoiItemReader reader = new PoiItemReader();
        reader.setResource(new InputStreamResource(new PushbackInputStream(new FileInputStream(xlsFile))));
        reader.setRowMapper(mapRowMapper());
        reader.setSheet(sheetConfig.getSheetIndex());
        reader.setLinesToSkip(sheetConfig.getLinesToSkip());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    @DependsOn
    public RowMapper mapRowMapper() throws IOException {
        return new MapRowMapper();
    }

}
```

The listener is :

```
public class XlsStepExecutionListener implements StepExecutionListener, InitializingBean {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XlsStepExecutionListener.class);

    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[sheetConfig]}")
    private SheetConfig config;

    @Value("#{jobParameters['isFull']}")
    private  boolean isFull;

    @Value("#{stepExecutionContext[supp]}")
    private String supp;

    private DataSource dataSource;


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(dataSource, "dataSource must be provided");
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {

        LOGGER.info("Start - Import sheet {}", config.sheetName);
        dataSource.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

        JdbcTemplate jt = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

        if(config.sqlDelete != null){
            //DELETE DATA
            LOGGER.info("beforeStep - PURGE DATA"+config.getSqlDelete().replaceAll("#TABLE#", config.getTable()));
            jt.update(config.getSqlDelete().replaceAll("#TABLE#", config.getTable()),supp);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        LOGGER.info ("End - Import sheet {}",config.sheetName);
        //TODO : 
        //If status failed -> rollback, if status success : commit
        return ExitStatus.COMPLETED;
    }

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }


}
```

In the pom.xml, I have the oracle jar :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I see that the class XMLType is in another jar of Oracle, but I don't know why I need to add this jar when I simply do a modification of auto commit mode ?
Also, I see that, for ALL the method I can call from getConnection().XXXX, the same exception happen. So it's not specific to the auto commit.

Thank you

Comment: I'd interpret it Oracle uses this jar internally. While using Spring or other Java framework a large number of dependencies should not surprise you. Add the jar to the CLASSPATH and go ahead;)

Comment: Yes but why this framework is need to access to the connection ? It's weird no ? Also, I can't find this jar because it seems to be included in odbc6.jar now...

Comment: xdb.jar is part of full oracle client and you cant find it in maven repos.  see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529215/where-to-get-oracle-jar-files-for-11-2-0-3-xdb-aq-i18n-xmlparser). I don't see dependency between autocommit and xml. however if you try to store xml (dom) somewhere then ojdbc will try to use xmltype - if so, convert it to string (clob).

Comment: I don't use any xml, only number and string, very basic things... They seems to be not available through maven directly but I can download them and add them to the lib, but it's weird that I need them. I will try it tomorrow but I'm not sure it's gonna solve anything...

Comment: So, it works with xdb6 dependency. But now the autoCommit still true even after a setAutoCommit(false)...

Comment: with new driver versions 19.6.0.0 with classes are split into different jars. So you would need ojdbc10.jar plus xdb.jar. Check [this article](https://medium.com/oracledevs/all-in-and-new-groupids-oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-a76d545954c6).